# firestore orderBy fails on multiple orderBy

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Receiving this error: '2022-09-02T07:05:40.698Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.3): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}'

My code:

```
const db = getFirestore(app);
const ref = collection(db, collectionName);
const q = query(ref, orderBy('name.last'), orderBy('name.first'));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    if (!stateError) {
      setStateError(undefined);
    }

    setStateValue(querySnapshot);
    if (stateLoading) {
      setStateLoading(false);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Did you create a composite index for `name.last` and `name.first`? If not, that would explain the error - and the error message should include a link to the Firebase console that allows you to create the necessary index with a single click.

Comment: after creatinga  manual index on name.last and name.first, the query does work again. the error message did NOT include a build link - which is not what is expected. I'm wondering if I need to downgrade my version of firebase... (another project I'm working on with a different version of firebase provides the link on this type of query/error...)

Comment: looks like it's some kind of library error. I've just upgraded to firebase 9.9.4, and i can now add a where clause (that match firebase rules of indexing, which I couldn't do in 9.9.3). however, the error output still does not include the link to build an index should my where clauses get a bit more complicated.

Comment: Have you checked this [Github link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/515#issuecomment-349610943)?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Error checking the firestore way is hidden in plain site in the documentation.

Working section of code:

```html
unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
        q,
        (snapshot) => {
          if (!stateError) {
            setStateError(undefined);
          }

          setStateValue(snapshot);

          if (stateLoading) {
            setStateLoading(false);
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          setStateError(error);
          if (stateLoading) {
            setStateLoading(false);
          }
          setStateValue(undefined);
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(error);
        },
      );
```

The bit that is new is the error block. The code still errors when an index is required, but, the error is now meaningful and actionable.

Comment: i had been wrapping this in a try catch block and the error was not being passed. this is because I wasn't utilising the error callback (it's in the documentation, but a few examples down). having the error returned means if an index is required for example, that gets reported as expected.